# How to get all text boxes of a process?

Tags: c#

I have C# application that should find all text boxes of a certain application.

```
foreach (Process procesInfo in Process.GetProcessesByName("AppTest"))
{
    Console.WriteLine("process {0} {1:x}", procesInfo.ProcessName, procesInfo.Id);
}
```

I want to get a list of all text boxes in AppTest.exe. AppTest.exe is a WPF application which contains some text boxes which are nested in other elements. I have to catch an event when one of those text boxes was clicked on. I need to get handle of clicked text box.

Comment: The System.Windows.Automation namespace was designed for this sort of thing.

Comment: Can you post a piece of code?

Comment: [This may get you started](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.automation.automationelement.findall(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: Can I set an mouse click event handler in Automation and detect a control that was clicked?

Comment: Listen for the focus change event. That catches cases where the user tabs to the edit control.

Comment: Focus change event in AutomationElement?

Comment: I'm counting on you to do your own reading.